# How to echo "$$PARAMTER_NM=1234"

Tags: shell

How can I print `$$PARAMTER_NM=1234` in a Linux shell? I am getting the PID of my current process with `$$`, so the output is like:

```
1943PARAMTER_NM=1234
```

But I need:

```
$$PARAMTER_NM=1234
```

Comment: See also [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '$$PARAMTER_NM=1234'
$$PARAMTER_NM=1234
```

Answer (score 1):

You can protect the contents of the string from the shell in two possible ways:

- Escape each `$` like `\$`:

  ```bsh
  echo "\$\$PARAMTER_NM=1234"
  ```
- Use single quotes:

  ```bsh
  echo '$$PARAMTER_NM=1234'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
# echo "\$\$PARAMTER_NM=1234"
$$PARAMETER_NM=1234
```

If you want to use a special/reserved character with double quotes (such as $) as-is - you need to use an escape character ('\') right before it.